# budget's funds (Why are "budget" and "funds" used together?)

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

A native speaker wrote the below sentence as a sample sentence for me to study. I don't understand "budget’s funds". "Budget" is money. "Funds" are also money. Why say money twice? Also, does "funds" mean "a sum of money saved or made available for a particular purpose"?

> The table displays the sources of the **budget’s funds** while the
> charts show how the funds were spent.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English, "budget" as a noun can mean just money in a casual sense, but it more commonly means a scheme (or plan) to spend money. A budget is a plan describing what various things funds will be spent on.

The Cambridge English dictionary defines budget as "a plan to show how much money a person or organization will earn and how much they will need or be able to spend" ( https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/budget )

The plan (budget) has an amount of money (funds) to allocate. In the example you gave, the illustration shows where that money came from, and what the plan allocated that money to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now know that in that sentence, "budget" means "plan". Can you tell me if "budget" means "money" or "plan" in the title of the table—Police Budget 2017-2018?

Comment: It means "plan" specifically ""a plan to show how much money the police received and how they were able to spend"